Use native Excel functions to count occurrences over threshold
I am trying to work out how to do the following. I have two Excel sheets: one for data and one for stats. The data sheet stores the number of units bought by each named customer - on multiple occasions. The stats sheet has a single row for each customer name - but should show in a separate column how many times the units bought exceeded a certain threshold.
For example:

And:

I am adept at VBA, and could produce a custom function to do this. However, I want to find a way to do this within non-VBA formulæ: i.e standard Excel nested formulas. This is because it is for a corporate spreadsheet, where the management wants to keep things as simple as possible - in xlsx format.
I'm sure it could involve a COUNTIFS function - but can’t quite get my head around which combination of native functions to use. Any assistance gratefully received.

Are there any restrictions on Excel version?

@Excellor We use Office 365. The exact version of this installation is Version 2308, Build 16.0.16731.205421 - 32 bit

=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B$2:B$10,">5",Sheet1!A$2:A$10,A2) in B2 and copy down.

Assuming that the name of the sheet where the data are is Sheet1, place this formula in the stats sheet's cell B2 and copy down till the end of the names, will return the required result:
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B$2:B$10,">5",Sheet1!A$2:A$10,A2)
actual range sizes and limit are according to the screenshots.

Try using the following formula:


• Formula used in cell E2
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,D2:D4,B2:B10,">=5")


Or, if applicable use GROUPBY()


=GROUPBY(A2:A10,B2:B10,ROWS,,0,,,B2:B10>=5)


Or, Using LET() with a combination of HSTACK()+UNIQUE()+COUNTIFS()
=LET(
     _CustName, A2:A10,
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_CustName),
     HSTACK(_Uniq, COUNTIFS(_CustName,_Uniq, B2:B10,">=5")))



Thanks - I'll try this and let you know if it works later today!

Only a caveat @ChrisMelville since you said, Number of times more than 5 units bought then it will be only ">5" and not ">=5" but as per your screenshot the expected output returns as ">=5"

Yes I know - I realised only after I had taken the screenshot :)

By the way - Black Cat answered in the comments with a very simple solution, which I will accept as the answer as soon as it is posted as an answer. But thank you so much for your efforts anyway.

@ChrisMelville therefore there is nothing wrong in the answer, and it does resolves the query. However, yes since you are using two different sheets which i have not specifically shown the syntaxes, but one can easily understand if they are using excel that they have to change the ranges and cell reference as per their suit.

@ChrisMelville even the answer which i have given is simple and more readable with other available options well before posted by black cat or something which is well 6 minutes before. Accepting or not accepting it depends on you however, the solution posted does resolves the problem

Mayukh Bhattacharya

Thank you, I unserstand that. It's just that Black Cat's solution was simpler :)


We could create a table for the data - in addition to easy reference, it is accessible from all sheets. Here I added a helper column also to use it with Pivot Table.
Using Pivot Table:

Using this helper function for counting (as we cannot use COUNTIF with arrays)
distinct_count: =LAMBDA(arr,  LET(uniq, UNIQUE(arr),  freq, MAP(uniq, LAMBDA(u, SUM(--(u=arr)))),  HSTACK(uniq, freq)  ))
we get the result with:
=distinct_count(
FILTER(
Table1[Customer Name],
Table1[Units Bought] >= _limit))



